# "failed to find package directory" error on Travis-CI while computing code coverage

Tags: r, testing, code-coverage, travis-ci, r-package

I am no longer getting code coverage for R package using `covr` on Travis (e.g., [this build](https://travis-ci.org/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/jobs/557831194)) and it gives the following error:

[image]

Travis never encountered any issues before, as can be seen from the following [commits log](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/commits/master) and suddenly it stopped working-

[image]

Here is a link to the GitHub repo for this package that contains all necessary details (like `yaml` files for `travis-ci` and `codecov`):
https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot

Any ideas on how to get rid of this error and get travis to provide code coverage percentages for PRs and master branch again?

**P.S.** 
In case you are wondering, this app `codecov` also has authorization to access data from this repo:

[image]

Comment: Can you check your integration with codecov here: https://github.com/settings/installations?

Comment: @DominicJodoin I have edited my question to contain this information.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not sure where this is coming from but I think I would look on Codecov's side: https://codecov.io/gh/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot. Isn't there any diagnostic tools available?

Comment: and could you also ensure that the `IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot` repository is selected when you click on the "Configure" button beside Codecov at https://github.com/settings/installations?

Comment: The logs you're seeing on Travis don't really match the ones I had on my build, but given the fact that you started having problems when you switched to `{{`, there's a good chance it is causing problems with `covr`, see [this](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/813) and [this](https://github.com/r-lib/covr/issues/377).

Comment: @Alexis Thanks! That is definitely a possibility. I will follow those issues and see if something helpful comes along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out this had to do with the newly introduced `{{` operator in `rlang` and `covr`'s interpretation of it.

After this [issue](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/813) was resolved, the Travis-CI has started running code coverage again.